# Is there any way to detect java server application is online automatically through android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a android application which makes client server communication over Socket. 
The server is on java application(desktop) & client is android app.
Problem: I don't want the user to go and connect to it. I just want the app to detect that the java app is online and connect to it automatically without knowing the user.

Comment: Make an api call to your java server, check for a response success response. If success, you can consider it as the java server app is running without any problem. :)

Comment: _I don't want the user to go and connect to it_ expand this

Comment: to have a cake and eat the cake

Comment: @JigarJoshi  i don't want the user to connect to server by pressing a button. I want my android app to detect automatically that the server is online and it connects to it automatically.

Comment: This is very basic thing to do. Answer is Yes you can. You can use background thread and call to network connection without having user to trigger manually. Question is too broad and basic.

Comment: Just try to connect to the server as you would normally, and handle the failure if and when it arises.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your android app is coded in java.

For communication to server I would use something like this:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        if (connected == false)
            {
              hostAvailabilityCheck();
            }
        }
    };

public static boolean hostAvailabilityCheck() { 
    try (Socket s = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, TCP_SERVER_PORT)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        /* if errors */
    }
    return false;
}
```

Anyway, I cant help you any further because I dont know how your code looks like.